# Whats that percentage mean in iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I'm starting to publish apps and I'm curious about this green number in iTunes Connect:

[image: green]

I believe it indicates growth over three hundred something. Can someone explain what this is? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows the change in units **since the prior range of data**. In the screenshot, 31 units is an increase of 343% over the previous data range.